# How does GreenPlum split data into different segments?

Tags: greenplum

I would like to ask what rules does GreenPlum separate it's tables into segments.

Does it evenly separate data into segments or according to block size?

Or depends on other characteristic of the data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two different ways.

1. Distribution key

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE foo
(id int, bar text)
DISTRIBUTED BY (id);
```

This will spread the data the id column.  You should pick a column or set of columns that will spread the data evenly across the database.  If the table is very large and you join it to another table that is also very large, you may want to distribute both tables by the same keys.

2. Random

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE foo
(id int, bar text)
DISTRIBUTED RANDOMLY;
```

This distributes the data in a random fashion.  Use this for small tables or if there isn't a natural key to the table.

You can also see how the distribution by using the hidden column "gp_segment_id".

```
select gp_segment_id, count(*) from foo group by gp_segment_id order by gp_segment_id;
 gp_segment_id | count 
---------------+-------
             0 |  1654
             1 |  1655
             2 |  1665
             3 |  1661
             4 |  1682
             5 |  1683
```

Comment: Hi, say if I distributed by key, and there are 5 segments in the system, how would this to be distributed? evenly to the 5 segments? or pack it into similar size blocks? what if new segment were added after it is distributed, what if each segments have different level of storage space??

Comment: Think rows.  ID=1 goes to segment 1, ID=2 goes to segment 2, etc.  If you add segments, you have to redistribute the data.

Comment: When you add a new segment, it is empty at the beginning. You redistribute all tables, and the distribution key picks up the new number of segments and redistributes the data across all segments.

Comment: `distributed randomly` isn't actually random, but rather a misnomer for round-robin distribution, says the [doc](https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/5230/admin_guide/ddl/ddl-table.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your data is evenly distributed if there are enough different values in your distribution key. A primary key or a unique key are good candidates for that.

If your distribution key has only a few distinct values, each row with the same value ends up on the same segment. That's an uneven distribution, some segments have to do all the work and others will be idle.

Example: if you chose gender as distribution key, you (usually) end up with 2-3 values: female/male/unknown. Let's leave other possible values aside here.
In this scenario you have 2-3 distinct values, and 2-3 different segment databases will hold all rows. Worst case: these 3 segment databases are all on the same physical host.